# Unknown Symbol ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

I want to compile this class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
public class Main implements ActionListener {
    private static JFrame frm = new JFrame();
    private static JLabel username = new JLabel("User:");
    private static JLabel password = new JLabel("Pass:");
    private static JTextField username_field = new JTextField();
    private static JPasswordField password_field = new JPasswordField();
    private static ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    private static JCheckBox sp = new JCheckBox ("Singleplayer");
    private static JCheckBox mp = new JCheckBox("Multiplayer");
    private static JButton play = new JButton("Play");
    private static JPanel p = new JPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().initFrame();
    }
    public void initFrame() {
        //Init Frame Stuff
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getActionCommand().equals("play")) {
            //Other Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

As you see above, I already imported ActionListener, but if I compile the code I get an Unknown Symbol Error:

```
.\GamePanel.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
 public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
 symbol: class ActionListener
 1 error
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Where is the `GamePanel` class? You have posted the wrong class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the specific error, you have to import the relevant package. Add

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

in the file `GamePanel.java`, right before the class declaration i.e. before the `public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {`

Comment: The class he shows is `Main.java` I think he forgot it in the other file

Comment: I know little mistake from myside ;)